# JavaScript - identify the object with a unique property

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I have managed to identify the highest number out of the count properties however I want to log the object associated with that number, i.e. log the object with the highest count number. How do I do this?

```
var objects = {

    object1: {username: 'mark', count: 3},
    object2: {username: 'dave', count: 5},
    object3: {username: 'lucy', count: 2},
};

var maxBap = Math.max.apply(Math,objects.map(function(o){return o.count;}));
console.log(maxBap);
```

Thanks

Comment: Is `objects` actually an array? Objects don't provide the `map` function.

Comment: Sorry yes it is supposed to be an array of objects

Comment: `var objects = [

 object1= {username: 'mark', count: 3},
 object2= {username: 'dave', count: 5},
 object3= {username: 'lucy', count: 2},
];`

Comment: Then maybe edit your question! Also, `[object1= {...} /* ... */]` is not valid syntax.

Comment: @rcsole: Technically it's valid syntax *(unless you're in strict mode)*, but most likely not what the OP intended.

Comment: You're right, I stand corrected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.map()`, use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the desired target.

Here I'm returning the key of the result object. You could return the object directly if you wish.

```js
var objects = {
    object1: {username: 'mark', count: 3},
    object2: {username: 'dave', count: 5},
    object3: {username: 'lucy', count: 2},
};

var res = Object.keys(objects).reduce(function(resKey, key) {
  return objects[resKey].count > objects[key].count ? resKey : key
})

document.querySelector("pre").textContent = res + ": " +
  JSON.stringify(objects[res], null, 4);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

---

If `objects` was meant to be an Array, you can still use `.reduce()`, just without `Object.keys()`. This returns the objects directly, which was alluded to in the first solution.

```js
var objects = [
    {username: 'mark', count: 3},
    {username: 'dave', count: 5},
    {username: 'lucy', count: 2},
];

var res = objects.reduce(function(resObj, obj) {
  return resObj.count > obj.count ? resObj : obj
})

document.querySelector("pre").textContent =
  JSON.stringify(res, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you. One more thing how do I just log the username of the highest count, i.e. so it just logs 'dave'

Comment: @mellows: Use the typical property access `.username`. So for the first solution: `objects[res].username`, and for the second `res.username`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.reduce` instead of `.map`.

```
const objects = [
  { username: 'mark', count: 3 },
  { username: 'dave', count: 5 },
  { username: 'lucy', count: 2 },
]

const max = objects.reduce((acc, obj) => (
  obj.count > acc.count ? obj : acc
))

console.log(max)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first find `max` of count and then find object with that count

```js
var objects = {
    object1: {username: 'mark', count: 3},
    object2: {username: 'dave', count: 5},
    object3: {username: 'lucy', count: 2},
}, result = null;

var max = Math.max.apply(null, Object.keys(objects).map(e => {return objects[e].count}));

for (var obj in objects) {
  if (objects[obj].count == max) result = objects[obj];
}

console.log(result)
```